# Ctrl+arrow - "Next Word" key binding not working

Tags: java, eclipse

Suddenly i found that Ctrl+arrow that helps to navigate between words stopped working in my Eclipse 2018-12 IDE. I see this key combination in Window->preferences->Keys and it is set when to in Windows. 
How to enable this function back?

[image]

Comment: Look at <workspace>/.metadata/.log, there should be an indication of key binding conflict. In other words, some IDE plugin or other application has registered that globally.

Comment: Check in the Keys preferences if `CTRL + Right` is assigned to something else also

Answer (score 0):

I had similar Issues

#### Virtual Box

When I was developing inside a Virtual Box Machine I got the exact same problem. The "Host key combination" was preventing it.. So turning off the host key did fix the problem.

#### Linux

Some linux Desktop Systems have default shortcuts which collides with eclipse short cuts.
(e.g. keys for switching Desktop workspaces) So you have to check if there are any collisions. If so, change the setup in Linux Desktop environment.

#### Windows

I had a preinstalled Snapshot program on my company windows PC which always respond to some of the eclipse short cuts as well. Maybe you got also a "brand new tool" which does something in such way.